# When having two actions with the same name and using ActionName, do I need to use Authorize on both of them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the below code in my `Controller`.
`Authorize` is correctly keeping people who aren't in that list out of the `Delete` action.

Do I need to do the same for the `DeleteConfirmed` action or is it already protected since it uses `ActionName("Delete")`?

```
// GET: Conversions/Delete/5
[Authorize(Users = "Mydomain\\MyUserName")]
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Conversion conversion = db.Conversions.Find(id);
        if (conversion == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(conversion);
    }

// POST: Conversions/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Conversion conversion = db.Conversions.Find(id);
        db.Conversions.Remove(conversion);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each action you need protected needs `[Authorize]`. It doesn't matter if they have the same action name or not. However, you don't need to actually place the `[Authorize]` attribute action by action. You can put it on the controller, instead, and then every action inside is protected as well. If there's a particular action you don't want protect, you can add `[AllowAnonymous]` to that.